# Xcode project error

Tags: xcode, error-handling, helper

I can not give much information, put when I play the project, it pauses. Please follow the following link to see the project on GitHub: https://github.com/ollie5511/Xcode-Game.git

Comment: What of your code do you think is at fault? What have you tried? Does the app literally pause execution in Xcode, or does it just crash?

Comment: @TheKraken I stops, and then opens Xcode and it says `paused` and the bottom bar opens.

Comment: Does the debugger highlight any part of your code in green, indicating a runtime error?

Comment: @TheKraken It highlights `[super viewDidLoad];`The bottom left says `self=ViewController*0x0747f4d0` And the `all output` says `(lldb)`

Comment: That indicates a logic error with the project. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it appears that you have an `int` variable declared directly after your `@implementation` call in your `ViewController.m` file. Variables can only be declared in your `@interface`, or in the class's methods.

Move or delete `int x = 0;`, and your code should execute.